# AWS Cloudformation SSM automation document | use with aws cloudformation package

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli, aws-ssm

in AWS Cloudformation I could use the `cloudformation package` command via CLI. This works for example with Lambdas:

```
lambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: helloWorld.lambda_handler
      Role: !GetAtt lambda.Arn
      Code: lambda/helloWorld.py
```

Now, I would like to to the same like `Code: lambda/helloWorld.py` within Systems Manager automation documents.

For example instead of the line `Restart-Computer -Force` under `commands:` I would like to use external skripts like this below (`commands: scripts/restart.ps1`):

```
#---Original

[...]
- name: restartEC2Instance
action: aws:runCommand
maxAttempts: 3
timeoutSeconds: 600
inputs:
  DocumentName: AWS-RunPowerShellScript
  InstanceIds:
    - "{{ InstanceId }}"
  Parameters:
    commands: |
      Restart-Computer -Force
    executionTimeout: "600"
[...]

#---Desired

[...]
- name: restartEC2Instance
action: aws:runCommand
maxAttempts: 3
timeoutSeconds: 600
inputs:
  DocumentName: AWS-RunPowerShellScript
  InstanceIds:
    - "{{ InstanceId }}"
  Parameters:
    commands: scripts/restart.ps1
    executionTimeout: "600"
[...]
```

Do you know any possibility to realize this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There is command documment called [AWS-RunRemoteScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/run-remote-documents.html):

> You can run SSM documents from **remote locations** by using the AWS-RunDocument pre-defined SSM document. This document currently supports the following remote locations: GitHub repositories (public and private), **Amazon S3**, Documents saved in Systems Manager

However, if you want the CLI to automatically upload your local file to S3, like it does for lambda, then this  functionality is sadly **not supported for SSM** documents. The automatic upload of local artifacts is only supported for the [following](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) CFN resource types:

```
BodyS3Location property for the AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi resource
Code property for the AWS::Lambda::Function resource
CodeUri property for the AWS::Serverless::Function resource
DefinitionS3Location property for the AWS::AppSync::GraphQLSchema resource
RequestMappingTemplateS3Location property for the AWS::AppSync::Resolver resource
ResponseMappingTemplateS3Location property for the AWS::AppSync::Resolver resource
DefinitionUri property for the AWS::Serverless::Api resource
Location parameter for the AWS::Include transform
SourceBundle property for the AWS::ElasticBeanstalk::ApplicationVersion resource
TemplateURL property for the AWS::CloudFormation::Stack resource
Command.ScriptLocation property for the AWS::Glue::Job resource
DefinitionS3Location property for the AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine resource
```